# How to introspect materialized views

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, information-schema, postgresql-9.3

I have a utility that introspects columns of tables using:

```
select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns
        where table_name=%s
```

How can I extend this to introspect columns of materialized views?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your query carries a few shortcomings / room for improvement:

- A table name is **not unique** inside a database, you would have to narrow down to a specific schema, or could get surprising / misleading / totally incorrect results.
  It's much more effective / convenient to cast the (optionally) schema-qualified table name to [**`regclass`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) ... see below.
- A cast to [regtype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) gives you generic type names instead of internal ones. But that's still only the base type.
  Use [the system catalog information functions **`format_type()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) instead to get an exact type name including modifiers.
- With the above improvements you don't need to join to additional tables. Just [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html).
- Dropped columns reside in the catalog until the table is vacuumed (fully). You need to exclude those.

```
SELECT attname, atttypid::regtype AS base_type
              , format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS full_type
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped;  -- no dead columns
```

As an aside: the views in the [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html) are only good for standard compliance and portability (rarely works anyway). If you don't plan to switch your RDBMS, stick with the catalog tables, which are *much* faster - and more complete, apparently.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup and notes!

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that postgres 9.3 has left materialized views out of the information_schema. (See http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Re-Materialized-views-WIP-patch-td5740513i40.html for a discussion.)

The following will work for introspection:

```
select attname, typname 
from pg_attribute a 
join pg_class c on a.attrelid = c.oid 
join pg_type t on a.atttypid = t.oid
where relname = %s and attnum >= 1;
```

The clause `attnum >= 1` suppresses system columns. The type names are pg_specific this way, I guess, but good enough for my purposes.